# I need to iterate an array over columns of my table in a blade file

Tags: html, css, laravel-blade

I need a table which I can iterate data of my table over its columns.
like [image: This]

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr colspan="2">کارکرد</tr>
        <tr colspan="2">پرداخت</tr>
        <tr colspan="2">کسور</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

please help me out here
The issue is I should iterate each column of data separately, and I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Can you specify how the data structure ?

Comment: convert your data structure to array of array and take transpose then iterate normally

Comment: @AbinThaha I have two arrays of data and one object. The object should go in the first column and the other two arrays should go to the second and third columns.

Comment: @Abhi Thanks but it doesn't work for me.